# How can I call the api repeatedly in supertest?

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

I want to test create, findById, and GetList that express api.
And I want to call create api repeatedly for test getlist function.
But If I use for loop syntax, that occurred TCPWRAP error.
How can I call the api repeatedly in supertest?

```js
    test("Make Some Products (10)", (done)=> {
        for(let i=0;i<10;i++) {
            agent
            .post(`/api/product`)
            .send({
                ...productJson,
                title: productJson.title + String(i),
            })
            .expect(200)
            .end((err, res) => {
                if(err) throw err;
                expect(res.body.success).toBeTruthy();
                productIds.push(PRODUCT_ID);
            });
        }
        done();
    });
```

Comment: `await` each request? Then you can get rid of the somewhat archaic `done` function - see https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not the correct way of writing tests.

1- If you want to test `create` function, then there is no need for the loop. Only one call is adequate.

2- If you want to test `getList` function, then you should not use expect() when you are populating the database. You only need expect() to check the return value of your `getList`.

3- A better way to populate database is to use your database module's methods (for example mongoose's `model.save()`) in jest's `beforeEach()`.

```
beforeEach(() =>{
    // insert records and save their ids in productIds
});

test("getList", (done) =>{
    // test your api using the data inserted above
})
```